# Bitwise operations in Pandas that return numbers rather than bools?

Tags: python, pandas, bit-manipulation

#### Question

How can I perform bitwise operations in Pandas?

#### How `&` works on integers

On integers the `&` operator performs a bitwise mask

```
>>> mask = 0b1100  # 4 and 8 bits on
>>> 7 & mask
4
```

#### How `&` works in Pandas

Is there some way to perform bitwise masking operations in Pandas?  The `&` operator does something else.

```
>>> df = DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], columns=['data'])
>>> df.data & mask
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
Name: data, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
In [184]: df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], columns=['data'])

In [185]: mask = 0b1100

In [186]: np.bitwise_and(df['data'], mask)
Out[186]: 
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    4
4    4
5    4
6    4
7    8
Name: data, dtype: int64
```

It even returns a Series -- pretty cool!

Comment: Alternatively, `df["data"].values & 0b1100`.

Comment: One more suggestion `df['data'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x: x & mask)`

Comment: If performance is a concern, I would recommend not exploring the usage of apply & lambda.  On a Series of 238517 records, using the timeit module, I measured ~500 microseconds to both right shift & mask values using the accepted or .values & mask suggestion.
 
However, the apply+lambda approach consistently would take around 1 second.   Jumpin from microsecond measurements to seconds.