# Pandas: eror when checking for a binary flag pattern

Tags: python, pandas, series, binary-operators

I have a dataframe where one of the columns of type `int` is storing a binary flag pattern:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'flag': [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 3, 9, 11]})
```

I tried selecting rows with value matching 4 the way it is typically done (with binary and operator):

```
df[df['flag'] & 4]
```

But it failed with:

> KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"

How to actually select rows matching binary pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though in Pandas [`&` or `|` is used as a logical operator to specify conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388950/logical-or-bitwise-or-in-pandas-data-frame) but at the same time using a Series as an argument to allegedly logical operator [results not in a Series of Boolean values but numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231438/bitwise-operations-in-pandas-that-return-numbers-rather-than-bools/22231528#22231528).

Knowing that you can use any of the following approaches to select rows based on a binary pattern:

- Since result of `<int> & <FLAG>` is always `<FLAG>` then you can use:

  ```
  df[df['flag'] & 4 == 4]
  ```

which (due to the precedence of operators) evaluates as:

```
  df[(df['flag'] & 4) == 4]
```

- alternatively you can use `apply` and map the result directly to a `bool`:

  ```
  df[df['flag'].apply(lambda v: bool(v & FLAG))]
  ```

But this does look very cumbersome and is likely to be much slower.

In either cases, the result is as expected:

```
    flag
2   4
3   5
4   7
```

Answer (score 1):

The bitwise-flag selection works as you’d expect:

```
>>> df['flag'] & 4
0    0
1    0
2    4
3    4
4    4
5    0
6    0
7    0
Name: flag, dtype: int64
```

However if you pass this to `df.loc[]`, you’re asking to get the indexes `0` and `4` repeatedly, or if you use `df[]` directly you’re asking for the column that has `Int64Index[...]` as column header.

Instead, you should force the conversion to a boolean indexer:

```
>>> (df['flag'] & 4) != 0
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
Name: flag, dtype: bool
>>> df[(df['flag'] & 4) != 0]
   flag
2     4
3     5
4     7
```